# Any difference between the Hybrid Use Windows Server image and the Existing Server License checkbox?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a difference between the "Save Money" checkbox as shown below and the Hybrid Use Windows Server 2016 VM image that's also shown below?

[image: Image showing the checkbox]

[image: Image showing the HUB Windows Server 2016 image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select `Save Momeny`, you select use `Azure Hybrid Use Benefit`.

`Azure Hybrid Use Benefit` is a new function provided with Azure.

> The Azure Hybrid Use Benefit helps you get more value from your
>   Windows Server licenses and save up to 40 percent* on virtual
>   machines. You can use the benefit with Windows Server Datacenter and
>   Standard edition licenses covered with Software Assurance. Depending
>   on the edition, you can convert or re-use your licenses to run Windows
>   Server virtual machines in Azure and pay a lower base compute rate
>   (Linux virtual machine rates).

Azure Hybrid Use Benefit FAQ please refer to this [link](https://ut5ff3npbyx1sqnpx41jwye1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Windows_Server_Azure_Hybrid_Use_FAQ_EN_US-April-2017.pdf).

Update:

Based on my knowledge, they are same.`HUB` is `Hybrid Use Benefit`. Use `HUB`, you could assign an existing Windows Server licence to it. You could refer to this [blog](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-debuts-new-bring-your-own-windows-server-license/).

Comment: Thanks, Walter. I understand Hybrid Use Benefit. It seems that there are two ways to create Windows 2016 with HUB and I am trying to understand what the difference between the two methods is. Thoughts?

Comment: If you don't use `Azure Hybrid Use Benefit`, you use the Windows License provided by Azure.

Comment: But, if you use `Azure Hybrid Use Benefit`, you could use own License. This could reduce your cost.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining myself very well.  The first screen shot is from a standard Windows Server 2016 image, which gives an option of selecting that checkbox to supposedly activate HUB.  The second screenshot is for a different Windows Server 2016 image with HUB enabled by default maybe?  So, are there two ways to activate HUB?

Comment: @thebitguru Sorry for my mistake. They are same. `HUB` is `Hybird Use Benefit` short. Use `Hub` . You could assign an existing Windows Server licence to it.

Comment: @thebitguru hi, do you have other question about `HUB`?

Comment: One other thing to add is that it seems that the HUB image requires Enterprise Agreement, but using the Windows 2016 Datacenter image and then checking seems to be work even without Enterprise Agreement (e.g. for companies that have been accepted into the BizSpark program).